# Why does the yield function not require parentheses in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, yield-keyword

In Python, I have many times seen the `yield` function used to create a generator. Both this and the `print` function technically both perform the action of methods because they return a value. However, during the change from Python 2 to Python 3, the `print` function gained parentheses like a normal method call, but yield stayed the same. Also, `yield` gains a yellowish color of a reserved keyword while `print` is the purple of a reserved method. Why is `yield` not considered a method and colored this way along with not using parentheses syntax?

(In a similar vein, why does `return` also lack parentheses?)

Let me add some more stuff, yield and continue are not given parentheses in many other languages as well. I just wanted to know what makes it different other than it is reserved. There are many other reserved methods out there which get parentheses.

Comment: Its not a function

Comment: It gives back a value, however

Comment: Why someone down voted this question? It's look ok for me.

Comment: *points at the lack of parens for `return`*

Comment: Dang forgot about that too thanks NightShadeQueen

Comment: Because that's the way the language is specified. You may just as well ask why the keywords are in English rather than Esperanto :-) I'm having difficulty figuring out how an answer will actually be useful to anyone other than as a curiosity.

Comment: Your answer is in [PEP 255](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/). In the future, if you want to know why something is some way in python, check out the relevant [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/).

Comment: @paxdiablo Yes, and I kind of realize how generators can control flow in code

Comment: Seriously, you differentiate between keywords and functions by their colours?

Comment: related https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40981/why-are-a-seemingly-disproportionate-amount-of-programmers-just-well-not-nice

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I went digging for an answer. [And it turns out, there is one](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/). From PEP 255, the pep that gave us the `yield` keyword

> Q. Why a new keyword for "yield"?  Why not a builtin function instead?
>
> A. Control flow is much better expressed via keyword in Python, and
>          yield is a control construct.  It's also believed that efficient
>          implementation in Jython requires that the compiler be able to
>          determine potential suspension points at compile-time, and a new
>          keyword makes that easy.  The CPython referrence implementation also
>          exploits it heavily, to detect which functions *are* generator-
>          functions (although a new keyword in place of "def" would solve that
>          for CPython -- but people asking the "why a new keyword?" question
>          don't want any new keyword).
>
> Q: Then why not some other special syntax without a new keyword?  For
>          example, one of these instead of "yield 3":

```
   return 3 and continue
   return and continue 3
   return generating 3
   continue return 3
   return >> , 3
   from generator return 3
   return >> 3
   return << 3
   >> 3
   << 3
   * 3
```

> A: Did I miss one ?  Out of hundreds of messages, I counted three
>          suggesting such an alternative, and extracted the above from them.
>          It would be nice not to need a new keyword, but nicer to make yield
>          very clear -- I don't want to have to *deduce* that a yield is
>          occurring from making sense of a previously senseless sequence of
>          keywords or operators.  Still, if this attracts enough interest,
>          proponents should settle on a single consensus suggestion, and Guido
>          will Pronounce on it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I just thought that since everything has been logical in programming so far, there has got to be a logic to this one.

Comment: @ytpillai Then thank goodness you are starting with Python and not PHP (or ksh) - else you might lose some hair!

Comment: I've heard PHP described as being like a toolbox where everything is just a little... [off](https://c4.staticflickr.com/8/7226/7095238893_5000f6e57d_b.jpg).

Comment: `yield` would make no sense to me as a function.  It doesn't behave like a function in any way. It's almost the exact opposite of a function, if you consider the call stack.

Answer (score 8):

`print` wasn't a function that gained parentheses: it went from being a statement to being a function. `yield` is still a statement, like `return`. Syntax highlighting is specific to your development environment.

You can find more information about [the difference between expressions and statements here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python), and more about [the difference between functions and statements here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307291/difference-between-statement-and-function). Also see the documentation on [simple statements](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html) and [compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html).

Comment: Why are these considered statements?

Comment: Why not the others, and just these?

Answer (score 2):

`yield` is not a function, its an keyword, and it does not require parenthesis according to [its grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-yield_atom) -

> yield_atom       ::=  "(" yield_expression ")"
>
> yield_expression ::= "yield" [expression_list]

`print` used to be a statement in Python 2 , but it was changed to being a built-in function in Python 3 using [PEP 3105](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/)

Comment: Did people just decide for `yield` to not get parentheses or is there some sort of logic or origin behind this concept?

Comment: No there is a sort of origin behind `print` becoming a function, yield as such is not an application level functionality , but `print` is , most other languages as well have `print` as a function , so having `print` as a statement would require interpreter to specially treat it and they did not want to do that.

Comment: Only function calls require parentheses. Please,go look at the python docs.

Answer (score 1):

`print` was a *keyword* defined by the *language specification* in Python 2, and became a *builtin* function (defined by the standard library specification) Python 3. `yield` was, and still is, a *keyword*.

Comment: Even if it is builtin, there are many other builtin functions like `hash()` and `set()` and the universal `int()`Why do those get parentheses?

Comment: They are **functions**.

Comment: How does something become a keyword and another thing a function?

Comment: I mean, they both act like a method that takes in data, processes, and gives back a value

Comment: In some way or the other

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trolling or just stubborn.  Get more familiar with  Python. Keywords are defined by the language.  They're special tokens that you use to access features of the *language* itself (like create functions or classes or do control flow). Functions on the other hand are ***code*** that you are executing when you call them.

Comment: Builtin functons are available without importing any libraries - theyre always available.

Comment: `int()` and `float()` and `list()` are all available as a default function, but I understand what you mean now. I am not trolling or being stubborn; this would be a pretty horrible attempt at it anyways. I just never realized that a generator can be used for control flow, etc. Notice I did not ask about `for` and looping and `if` statements

Comment: The `yield` statement does NOT take in data, does NOT process data, and does NOT return a value. You have completely mischaracterized what `yield` does. What it actually does is, trigger a control flow that causes the function that contains it to return a value (in a specific way that's distinct from non-generator functions). Why are you so mystified that `yield` isn't a function? It manifestly behaves in a manner entirely unlike a function.