# Function vs Statement in Python

Tags: python, definition

So I just started learning Python. In my book it was given that `print()` is a function in Python 3.x whereas it is a statement in Python 2.x

What exactly is the difference between a statement and a function?

Note - I am a beginner and excuse me if this seems too silly.

PS - I saw  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435850/what-is-the-difference-between-a-statement-and-a-function-in-python) answer but I couldn't understand it. Elaborating it would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435850/what-is-the-difference-between-a-statement-and-a-function-in-python

Comment: Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/9307291 for a slightly better answer that applies to many languages.

Comment: @iz_ So is statement the order given to the Python interpreter to take a specific action? Is function set of statements that perform a specific action (It can be used elsewhere in the program when needed)? Is it? Also, in Python 2.x `print "Hello World!"` is valid. Isn't?